# Call function after application close

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, exit, coroutine

I need to call a function after closing the application (windows standalone application) and not OnApplicationClose() function.

This function also depends on variables in the class (IntPtr variables).

I tried to make this function as IEnumerator and call it from OnApplicationClose() but I don't know if this will work or if it is the right way:

```
void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    StartCoroutine(OnClose());
}

private IEnumerator OnClose()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    // After close function
}
```

My problem is that the function that I want to call after application quit takes a long time so I need to close the application first and then call this function.

Comment: is that code what you want to perform is independent than your applicatio ( it's okay if it needs some input some input)? if yes, and if you have liberty to add additional application and batch file, you can call that batch file while closing the application, and that batch file will call the other application (which may take time but your main application can be closed soon after calling batch)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible via coroutine. Coroutines run on the main thread, which gets killed with your app.

However, if you are developing for android, you can write a service. Then in `OnApplicationQuit`, you can send a message via JNI to do whatever task you want.

Comment: Sorry for not mention that in the question but it is a windows standalone application

Comment: @BilalSehwail, Either use a new thread instead of a Coroutine, but be aware that you "You can't use any Unity functions in a Thread" [see comment here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/143454/unity-coroutine-vs-threads). 

Or: minimize your application, and quit when you are done. You could show a progress bar, if the application is brought to front before finishing.

Comment: @KYL3R For now, I will go with your suggestion (thread + minimize)